# How to take the values inside a div element , remove the <br> and turn the values into array with JavaScript ,no Jquery please

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, line-breaks

This is how the div looks like when i'm inspecting it in the dev tools :

```
<div>
    "some text"
    <br>
    "some text2"
    <br>
    <br>
    "some text3"
    <br>
    "some text4"
</div>
```

my problem is that i can't access this div element by doing doucument.querySelector(".myDiv");
because i'm doing this operation in an other program , and i only 
get the output like this :

some text

some text2

sometext3

sometext4

im trying to convert this output into an array , but split not working nor replace (//line break regex , ",")

expected result :

```
["some text", "some text2", "some text3", "some text4"];
```

thanks!

Comment: Elaborate your question with proper example and share what did you try.

Comment: Add your actual html

Comment: the empty lines are <br> tags

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, try this example:

```js
const divText = document.querySelector('.someDiv').innerText;
const requiredArray = divText.split('\n');
console.log(requiredArray);
```

```html
<div class="someDiv">
some text
<br>
other text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As there are two types of text into the `div` so you have to sanitize the extra things.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
const arr = div.innerText.split("\n");

// Removes the extra quote (") from the strings and drop any empty string from the array by using filter().
const result = arr.map(item => item.replace(/\"/g, '')).filter(item => item !== '');

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0;}
```

```html
<div>
    "some text"
    <br>
    "some text2"
    <br>
    <br>
    some text3
    <br>
    "some text4"
</div>
```